# vector of boost::function not working with _placeholder

Tags: c++11, vector, boost, function-pointers

I need your help. I tried a lot to find a solution for the problem but failed so far.

**Idea:**

Create a vector of "command tuples" like the following:

```
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, boost::function<void()>> command_tuple;

std::vector<command_tuple> commands {
  boost::make_tuple("command1", boost::bind(&myclass::command1, this))
};
```

If the string `"command1"` is used the `void command1()` function is called. The ID index value is based on `find_if` search for the string (`"command1"` is `ID=0`) on the vector.

This is working fine!

```
boost::get<1>(commands[ID])();
```

**Problem:**

I found no way so far to use a vector of boost::function (pointers) defined with any kind type of function parameters:

```
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, boost::function<void(const char *)>> command_tuple;

std::vector<command_tuple> commands {
  boost::make_tuple("command1", boost::bind(&myclass::command1, this, std::placeholders::_1))
};
```

This will fail with a **cannot convert std::_Placeholder<1> to type const char *** compilation error.

This is therefore not possible:

```
boost::get<1>(commands[ID])("dynamic string argument");
```

**Pinning down of the problem:**

hmmm ... so I found out so far that even a simple vector of boost::function does not seem to work (in the way I am trying to use it):

```
std::vector<boost::function<void(const char *)>> commands {
  boost::bind(&myclass:command1, this, std::placeholders::_1)
};
```

Fails with the same compilation error.

It is possible to replace the std::placeholders::_1 with "static string constants" to avoid any compilation errors. But my idea was to use a "dynamic string argument".

Can someone please give me a quick hint of what I am doing wrong or maybe show some simple alternatives. I want to have quite a big list of function pointers that I can call based on their "string name".

> I simply want to avoid a big "switch select case" style code block to
>   select the function to be executed based on a dynamic "input string".

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Placeholders are not interchangeable. `std::bind`'s placeholders can't be used with `boost::bind`.

Comment: argh! yes replacing boost::bind with std::bind is working great. feel kind of stupid now and sorry about time wasted today :)

Answer (score 0):

like T.C. replied in the comments. You should never mix std::bind, std::placeholders and boost::bind.